# How to drag from browser area and deposit to the explorer area?

Tags: java, javascript, drag-and-drop

Sometime ago I was facing the problem the other way around: how to drag an item (folder/file) from an explorer window (be it windows explorer, linux nautilus etc.) to the browser window - that is, the drag starts in one application and ends in the browser. Since I had control over the browser, I was able to intercept the dragend event: the one which interested me.

Now, I want to do this from the browser to the file explorer application: much like when you drag an image from firefox and drop it in a folder.

My main problem is that while I can check when the drag event exited the browser window, I have no ideea how to get the location where the drag event finished.

My ideea is to create a signed java applet and somehow track the mouse movement on the desktop - but this seems a little more than overkill.

Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your justification is is not simple, but it can be managed. There is class called DataFlavor. You had to use D&D mechanism introduce in java using Transferable objects and provide correct mime-types and corresponding conversion. The problem is which mime-type will be accepted by explorer. I hope this help.

Comment: I guess it will accept most of the main mime-types. I believe now that when the dragexit happens, I need to pass control over to the java applet and from there construct the Transferable objects.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with JavaScript. JS is sandboxed in the browser and can't interact with anything outside.

Comment: That I know. I am going to use JS only to detect the dragexit event from the html document, and pass control to the java signed applet. At least, that's the idea at this time.